# Append a dict in a nested dict python

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to have a dictionary appended with new dictionaries.

```
t = {}
t['bush_mod']={} # Toplevel
ana1 = {}
ana1['ana1_lin_001']={}
t['bush_mod'] = ana1 # Add below Toplevel

ana2 = {}
ana2['ana2_lin_001'] = {}
ana2['ana2_lin_002'] = {}

t['bush_mod'] = ana2 # Add below Toplevel
```

When I add `ana2` the dictionary `t` gets overwritten which i do not want.

```
OUT: {'bush_mod': {'ana2_lin_001': {}, 'ana2_lin_002': {}}}
```

I wanted to have `ana2` as the second dict (appended) below the Toplevel.

```
OUT: {'bush_mod': {'ana1_lin_001': {}},{'ana2_lin_001': {}, 'ana2_lin_002': {}}}
```

It would really be helpful if someone could help me with the syntax.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think what you want is a list

Comment: Of course it does, you are adding the same key with a new value.  You also cannot have the output you desire, if you want multiple values per key use a list as the value and append each new dict

Comment: Thanks for the reply..i modified it as a list to get it working

Comment: Output as `{'bush_mod': {'ana1_lin_001': {}},{'ana2_lin_001': {}, 'ana2_lin_002': {}}}` is not valid in syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to nested dictionaries I think `dict.update` might be an option:

```
t = {}
t['bush_mod']={}

ana1 = {}
ana1['ana1_lin_001']={}

ana2 = {}
ana2['ana2_lin_001'] = {}
ana2['ana2_lin_002'] = {}

t['bush_mod'].update(ana1)
t['bush_mod'].update(ana2)
```

Such that `t` is:

```
{'bush_mod': {'ana1_lin_001': {}, 'ana2_lin_001': {}, 'ana2_lin_002': {}}}
```

`dict.update` here adds the keys-value pairs from `ana1` and `ana2` to the dictionary `t['bush_mod`]`

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Now i need not modify the rest of my code ;) Thank you

Answer (score -2):

you need to use distinct keys for each element in the dict t... it is overriding because you used 'bush_mod' twice...

you need to make t['bush_mod']= [] then append that list with things.

```
t['bush_mod'] = []
t['bush_mod'].append(ana1)
t['bush_mod'].append(ana2)
```